# Specified method is not supported LINQ and MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I've tried to write a LINQ query that will give me all the details in one place, I need the date of production, the employee name and the sum of money this employee should get for his work. this is what I have so far:

```
var PrePerWorker =
                    (from Production in context.production
                    where Production.ProductionDate >= dtpStartDate.SelectedDate && Production.ProductionDate <= dtpEndDate.SelectedDate

                    select new
                    {
                        Worker = 
                            (from Employee in context.employees
                             where Employee.ID == Production.EmpID
                            select Employee.FirstName).FirstOrDefault(),
                        DateOfProduction = Production.ProductionDate,
                        Total =
                            Production.Side == 1 ? Production.Amount * 
                            (from Product in context.products
                             where Product.ProductID == Production.ProductID
                             select Product.SideA).FirstOrDefault():
                             Production.Side == 2 ? Production.Amount * 
                            (from Product in context.products
                             where Product.ProductID == Production.ProductID
                             select Product.SideB).FirstOrDefault():
                             Production.Side == 3 ? Production.Amount * 
                            (from Product in context.products
                             where Product.ProductID == Production.ProductID
                             select Product.SideC).FirstOrDefault(): 0
                    }).GroupBy(x => x.DateOfProduction, x => x.Worker);
```

When I run this and then try to iterate over the results I get an error saying "Specified method is not supported".
Anyone knows why? and how can I fix this?

Comment: Because your linq can't be translated to mysql query. And what you mean here".GroupBy(x => x.DateOfProduction, x => x.Worker);"?

Comment: what can I do then? and I meant to group by 2 "columns"

Comment: You effectively using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549270.aspx) of GroupBy, which apparently is not supported by the query provider. When it says "Specified method" I'd expect that some method is specified somewhere, is there? (Inner exception maybe?)

Comment: No there is none, I searched for it to search on the internet this is the inner exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the tertiary ? : operator can't be translated to SQL

Comment: So what can I do in order to get to my end result?

Answer (score 0):

For grouping by 2 columns you need `GroupBy(x => new {x.DateOfProduction, x.Worker});`. And can you explain what you need, because your linq looks like so hard for me.

Comment: Ok I need to show in a table all the worker names (hence the first name selection from the workers table), the date of production and how many did he make depended or the station he was working at. Then I need to sum it up to have the total for each day for each worker and then show it in a report. I hope I made myself clear if now please let me know.